# What's the meaning of "making a rake" in the following context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In a scene from a movie, someone approaches an Irish farmer, who is stacking piles of peat, and says:

"Your father was a great man for **making a rake**. Even the great storm of '05 never knocked his rake."

Does the word "rake" here mean the same "gardening tool with a row of metal teeth at the end"? I think these words have something to do with those piles of peat, but I'm not sure. The words about the storm confused me even more. Any ideas?

Comment: You tag "meaning-in-context" but have not provided a context for the sentence.

Comment: @WeatherVane That was the whole thing! There's nothing more to provide you with. As mentioned, I heard it in a scene from a movie, and the words before and after the sentence refer to a different topic.

Comment: You need to show what you have done to find out the meaning for yourself.

Comment: . . . and you need to show the movie clip, for the context.

Comment: @Tuffy I consulted a number of dictionaries for the meaning(s) of rake, but I'm not sure if any of these meanings fit the context above: 1. a garden tool; 2. the act of raking; 3. a slope.

Comment: Perhaps you missed a meaning of "rake" which is a **person** [described here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rake).

Comment: @WeatherVane - I don't see how that helps.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you didn't show the research you've done, and you didn't cite the specific source.  I do hope you'll edit and improve the question.  You've got me curious!

Comment: @aparente001 I was highlighting the lack of research, and without seeing the movie, it might be relevant.

Comment: Please bear in mind too, that a rake has no use for either cutting or stacking peat.

Comment: You don't have to provide the clip of the movie, but it would be nice to know its **title** and if possible the context that lead to the phrase being spoken.  This could be  slang, or it could be about pronunciation. Are you sure you heard "rake"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I heard that phrase in that context, I would assume it referred a "rick" or stack of peat, spoken with some old farmery accent. Its not a common usage, but there is precedent if you search for the phrase.

[image]

[Source: Image of a rick of peat](https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-gold-colored-straw-and-netting-holding-a-rick-of-peatturf-on-the-irish-1959874.html)

Comment: I've tidied up your link so you can see how it is done. Undo if you wish.

Comment: You might like to look at [this link](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Jr42HwoVNcIC&pg=PA98&lpg=PA98&dq=rick+rake+stack&source=bl&ots=ntr_TxQ-Gv&sig=nB2VCndDcScDrsYX6K9dDBIMn-4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGipjIjtTaAhUoKcAKHRUjByQQ6AEIXzAN#v=onepage&q=rick%20rake%20stack&f=false) which mentions ricks, stacks and 'push-rakes'.

Comment: @BeatsMe please accept Nom DaGruyere's answer.